# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException only with Kindle Fire Tablets in Amazon Store

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, kindle-fire, amazon-appstore

I have the following stacktrace reported in the **Amazon App Store**. I have three major problems with analyzing it:

1. I could never reproduce it, since it *only* seems to happen with
   Kindle Fire tablets and I don't have one
2. The stacktrace I have available *does not contain*
   my app package, so it's hard to figure out which line in my code
   causes that actually
3. It happens *only occasionally*, about 95% of
   Amazon Kindle fire sessions seem to be without any problem

**The stacktrace provided by Amazon Developer Reporting** (that is all I got from them...)

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:525)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
    at android.webkit.WebView$ActionPopupWindow.onClick(WebView.java:5867)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3540)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14167)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Additional infos about the devices it happens:** (according to Google Analytics App tracking)

1. Devices: Kindle Fire HD 7, Kindle Fire HD 8.9
2. OS: "Amazon" android 4.0.3 & 4.0.4

My interpretation of the stacktrace so far is that something goes wrong with a Dialog in my app, but it is so weird that on other devices than Kindle Fire it all works (incl. Froyo & Gingerbread devices!). And the line with the WebView confuses me, because I don't have a webview included anywhere..

There are some other questions about BadTokenException already, but what I have researched, the solutions don't seem to fit for my case. Like for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946783/android-dialogs-are-causing-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable) but I don't do multithreaded things within the app, so shouldn't work for me either. Maybe I missed something there?

Do you have any idea what can be the causing this? Since it only happens rarely and only Kindles it is not a big problem for me, but I would like to understand what is going on.

Edit: Another suspect is the Admob advertisment, that could explain the occasional occurence (maybe sometimes some sort of kindle-unfriendly ads show up?)

Comment: do you have an advertising API in the app? that might be rolling in a webview that's triggering the issue?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Yes I do! It could be that, I'll investigate the ads API a bit more. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right,this is exception regarding dialog itself.
I found few links.Hope it works for you.

```
http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/how-to-fix-windowmanager.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561803/android-progressdialog-show-crashes-with-getapplicationcontext
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034495/window-manager-bad-token-exception-android
```

The reason is that the sum times dialog box is unable to notice that its parent activity is finished or not.Most important observation is that it is rare and uncertain issue.

Comment: That looks like a good trace taking into account that I have just seen that Kindle seems to handle screenorientation changes a little different than "normal" android devices https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/clinton-teegarden/making-your-android-application-kindle-fire-ready because my app is fixed to portrait orientation in the Manifest file. Maybe Amazon Kindles do rotate screen 180º if it is upside-down although it is fixed to portrait? Google android devices wont do that if it is fixed to portrait.

Comment: Although I could not yet verify that is the reason yet it is at least a hot trace. And since it seems like nobody else (incl me) has a better answer you  deserve the bounty ;-) I will however update my app with some adjustments and will let you know if ocasional kindle crashes persist. Thx.

Comment: Of course,I will keep trying on my end too.Will notify you with more perfect solution as soon as I get.