# window manager bad token exception android

Tags: android

In my application I used tabhost with 3 tabs, and when ever I pressed the back button, I am getting [`WindowManager.BadTokenException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.BadTokenException.html) I tried alot of things, but am not able to sort it out.

Here is my activity background task:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    //  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Groupinion_MyStuff_Answer.this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        try {
            pDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return Utils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);



            if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }           
        }
    }       
}
```

Here is my Logcat

```
 02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@42161de0 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:720)
02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:356)
02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:234)
02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
02-26 12:56:58.765: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at com.android.groupinion.Groupinion_MyStuff_Answer$MyTask.onPreExecute(Groupinion_MyStuff_Answer.java:269)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at com.android.groupinion.Groupinion_MyStuff_Answer.onCreate(Groupinion_MyStuff_Answer.java:182)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at com.android.groupinion.Groupinion_Mystuff.replaceContentView(Groupinion_Mystuff.java:461)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at com.android.groupinion.Groupinion_Mystuff$3.onClick(Groupinion_Mystuff.java:202)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-26 12:56:58.775: W/System.err(30960):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should also post your logcat output

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,i updated the logcat also please suggest me

Comment: You are using the package name `com.android.groupinion`?

Comment: yes that is my package name

Comment: you own the domain `android.com` ? If not, then you should not use it as package name

Answer (score 3):

I guess that problem is with progressDialog. What I suggest is to define pDialog as a object in the activity at top(instead of object of the AsyncTask)

```
class MyActivity{
   ProgressDialog pDialog;
}
```

And before showing the dialog, check if activity has entered the finishing state.

```
if(!activity.isFinishing)
   pDialog.show();
```

and in your onDestroy method of the activity

```
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
       pDialog.cancel();
}
```

Comment: why you want to show progress dialog when Activity is finishing?

Comment: Hi i tried this but it showing progrss dialog for the first time when we open that activity,if i tried to open for the second time,it said the same exception

Comment: @GopalRao, when ever i opened that activity im downloading datas from web,so i used progress dialog

Comment: @gopalrao sorry i missed ! inside if. can you try again with the edited if(!activity.isfinishing)

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason is the context of the alert dialog. You may be finished that activity so its trying to open in that context but which is already closed.
Try changing the context of that dialog to you first activity beacause it won't be finished till the end.

e.g

rather than this.

```
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

try to use

```
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstActivity.getInstance()).create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);`, try:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(yourClass.this);
```

Notice the argument passed.